# Not getting any results from Web3j querying of ERC20 token's balanceOf() function

Tags: contract-invocation, web3j

I am trying to use Web3j to query the `balanceOf()` function of a standard ERC20 token as shown in the code below:

```
try {
        String encodedFunction = FunctionEncoder.encode(function);
        String contractAddress = "0x4330e0c338b48128a4534d90fd83579ef5539998";
        Address[] addressInput = new Address[]{new Address(fromAddress)};
        Function function = new Function(
                "balanceOf",
                Arrays.<Type>asList(addressInput),
                Arrays.<TypeReference<?>>asList(new TypeReference<Uint256>() {
                }));

        String fromAddress = "0x266d3299d8ede74e9dce770366bbe59179f676ef";
        EthCall response = web3j.ethCall(
                Transaction.createEthCallTransaction(fromAddress, contractAddress, encodedFunction),
                DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST)
                .sendAsync().get();

        if (response == null) {
            System.out.println("Nothing was returned !!!");
        } else {
            if (response.getValue() == null) {
                System.out.println("Nothing was returned !!!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Detected response ...");
                List<cryptocurrency.proto.eth.abi.datatypes.Type> someTypes = FunctionReturnDecoder.decode(
                        response.getValue(), function.getOutputParameters());

                System.out.println("Return Value(s)");
                System.out.println("===============");
                for (int i = 0; i < someTypes.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println("" + someTypes.get(i).getValue());
                }
            }
        }
} catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(TestERC20.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

The response is no response as shown below:

```
Detected response ...
Return Value(s)
===============
```

I am trying to querying this contract (https://ropsten.etherscan.io/token/0x4330e0c338b48128a4534d90fd83579ef5539998) using a token owner address of (https://ropsten.etherscan.io/token/0x4330e0c338b48128a4534d90fd83579ef5539998?a=0x266d3299d8ede74e9dce770366bbe59179f676ef).

What am I missing to get the above code to work on the `balanceOf()` method and return me the answer of the current holding amount of `999,981,060.605788211684519359 ZEN` tokens belonging to the above token owner address ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found out some missing variables that are causing my querying of balance to not work.

The reason is I did not fill in the parameter of the address I wanted to query.

The above codes have been edited and are now fully working to query an address's balance from a supplied contract address.

The output is now:

```
Detected response ...
Return Value(s)
===============
999981049099940051684519338
```

Which is the correct amount of tokens at the moment the query was executed.